# Eledmac line numbering out of margin at top of column (memoir)

Tags: memoir, two-column, line-numbering, eledmac

I'm using `eledmac` to typeset a document with two columns in memoir. The first line number at the top of the right column continues to be placed to the left of the column, as it was with the left column, rather than in the margin to the right. The same is true for the left column beginning on the second page (its first line number continues from the right column on the preceding page to be placed to the right of the column).

I thought of using the `multicol` package, but I need to use `eledmac` for the line numbering / critical apparatus. I also tried `eledmac`'s `\linenummargin` command, but without success. Sure I must be missing an easy workaround. Appending a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twocolumn,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verse}
\setlrmarginsandblock{.75in}{.75in}{1} 
\setulmarginsandblock{.75in}{.75in}{1} 
\checkandfixthelayout 
\setcolsepandrule{28pt}{0pt}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{2}
\lineation{page}
\linenummargin{right}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Hello World}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

and images of the much improved result thanks to David Carlisle's helpful responses (now it is just the top # on most pages that is off):
[image: lipsum ex.]
[image: my actual doc]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original version is at the end, this version saves the page as well as line number in the position information sp it can cope with the line number being re-set

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twocolumn,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verse}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{2}
\lineation{page}
\linenummargin{right}



\makeatletter


\def\eldefkey{\romannumeral\line@num @\romannumeral\c@page}

\let\saved@affixline@num\affixline@num
\def\affixline@num{{%
\pdfsavepos
\edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\string\eldef \romannumeral\line@num @\noexpand\romannumeral\c@page
{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}%
\tmp
\expandafter\ifx\csname eldef\eldefkey\endcsname\relax
\else
 \ifnum \csname eldef\eldefkey\endcsname=3818782 % 3818782
          \@firstcolumntrue
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\eldefkey\endcsname=25445662 % 19514654
     \@firstcolumnfalse
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\eldefkey\endcsname=5653790 % 5653790
          \@firstcolumntrue
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\eldefkey\endcsname=27280670 % 21349662
        \@firstcolumnfalse
\else
  \showthe\line@num
 \fi\fi\fi\fi
\fi
% force first number to first column
\ifnum\line@num=1
\@firstcolumntrue
\fi
\saved@affixline@num}}


\renewcommand*{\affixpstart@num}{%
    \ifsidepstartnum
        \if@twocolumn
            \if@firstcolumn
                  \gdef\l@dld@ta{\llap{QQQQ{\leftpstartnum}}}%
            \else
                  \gdef\l@drd@ta{\rlap{PPPP{\rightpstartnum}}}%
            \fi
        \else
             \@l@dtempcntb=\line@margin
            \ifnum\@l@dtempcntb>\@ne
                  \advance\@l@dtempcntb \page@num
            \fi
            \ifodd\@l@dtempcntb
                  \gdef\l@drd@ta{\rlap{XXXXX{\rightpstartnum}}}%
            \else
                  \gdef\l@dld@ta{\llap{YYYYY{\leftpstartnum}}}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi

}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Hello World}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

---

I didn't have the fonts so this is tested with the standard font setup, but appears to work.
Not a complete fix but a manual work-around for when things go wrong, the code added in the preamble forces the line number `30` to switch sides.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{eledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\linenummargin{left}
\makeatletter

\let\saved@affixline@num\affixline@num
\def\affixline@num{{%
\pdfsavepos
\edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{%
\gdef\string\eldef\romannumeral\line@num{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}%
\tmp
\expandafter\ifx\csname eldef\romannumeral\line@num\endcsname\relax
\else
 \ifnum \csname eldef\romannumeral\line@num\endcsname=3818782
          \@firstcolumntrue
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\romannumeral\line@num\endcsname=19514654
     \@firstcolumnfalse
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\romannumeral\line@num\endcsname=5653790
          \@firstcolumntrue
 \else \ifnum \csname eldef\romannumeral\line@num\endcsname=21349662
        \@firstcolumnfalse
\else
  \showthe\line@num
 \fi\fi\fi\fi
\fi
\saved@affixline@num}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Hello World}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks much for the idea. I'm sorry; I neglected to mention that my document is quite long, which makes implementing your manual fix less desirable. If it comes to that, it comes to that, but I'm hoping for a global fix. Thanks again.

Comment: automatic version added, will get it right on the second pass. the four numbers are the x-position of the first and second column on odd and even pages. they are correct for the document as posted if you change page size just copy them from the aux file. Any unexpected position will stop at the `\showthe` line

Comment: Thanks, that works for the mwe!  I didn't realize any solution given would conflict with other parameters I've set, but this one seems to.  Is it difficult to tweak this solution to deal with "landscape" in the doc class option and layout parameters of the following? \setlrmarginsandblock{.75in}{.75in}{1} \setulmarginsandblock{.75in}{.75in}{1} \checkandfixthelayout \setcolsepandrule{28pt}{0pt}

Comment: Hasty in my last reply...copying the .aux numbers now. Will report back shortly.

Comment: Hey, it basically works! But there are some factors that are throwing it off. I'm sorry not to have included them in the mwe, but I didn't know they would be relevant. I'm using \lineation{page}, which with this setup throws the numbering to the wrong side occasionally. Also, I'm using \setcounter{firstlinenum}{1} and \setcounter{linenumincrement}{2}, which with this setup really throws the numbering back and forth. Finally, the "verse" with (\altverse) package seems to be throwing things off as well. I'll update the mwe now...

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Your code works almost perfectly now. But this troubleshooting seems to reveal that the margin-measurements I mentioned above actually were also a contributing factor to my problem, because the top line number on many pages is still reversed for me. Would you mind plugging in those measurements (now in the mwe) to see if you get the same result? Thanks so much! I'll add a picture with my results.

Comment: Not sure what the package is doing with the first number (I'd never seen this package before this question:-) but anyway I put an override so the first line number is always in the first column.

Comment: Great improvement! Now I don't see the margin-switching until the 5th and 6th pages instead of on every page... Quite tricky this! Thanks again for all of your help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I think I give up, at this point it's now debugging someone else's package and probably more productive if you accept this for now, but contact the package maintainers, they could probably easily narrow down on the code dealing with page change and adapt the code above to work in all cases.

Comment: Agreed, I'll get in touch with the package maintainer. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Thanks, if you get a package update could you come back here and add a reference for the records.